# Reducing Thread contention on H2

Tags: java, h2

I'm trying to achieve better performance for insert on H2 from multiple threads.

I've tried four different setups, each with 20 concurrent threads doing inserts:

1. Shared connection;
2. Shared connection disabling autocommit;
3. Connection pool;
4. Connection pool disabling autocommit.

Got the best result with option 4:

[image: H2 Thread Contention]

Table created with:

```
create table foo (id int not null auto_increment primary key, name varchar(50))
```

Code for insert (`c` is a connection from `org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool`):

```
private static void insertDataWithConnection(Connection c, String n) throws SQLException {
    c.setAutoCommit(false);
    PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("insert into foo (name) values (?)");
    ps.setString(1, n);
    ps.executeUpdate();
    ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
    rs.next();
    rs.getInt(1);
    rs.close();
    c.commit();
    c.setAutoCommit(true);
    ps.close();
}
```

The connection string:

```
jdbc:h2:test;AUTOCOMMIT=OFF;WRITE_DELAY=300;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_MODE=0;FILE_LOCK=SOCKET
```

Is it possible to reduce the Thread contention somehow?

P.S.:

- Getting the generated key is important.
- Switching H2 to another embedded database may be an option; but, please, the answers should focus on H2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've used [Multi-version Concurrency control](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#mvcc) and [Multi-threaded](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#set_multi_threaded) options.  They do seem to help with some of the contention issues, but they were not a silver bullet.

Comment: I'm already using MVCC. Added the connection string to the question.

Comment: Did you try using the multi-threaded option? http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#set_multi_threaded

Comment: that's what i suggested in my answer

Comment: I'll consider your answer as correct, as this seems to be the best option to reduce thread contention.